# Is it possible to access a nested dictionary from Dotliquid?

Tags: .net, f#, dotliquid

I was wondering if it was possible to access a nested dictionary with the dotliquid library.

What I have got so far is this:

```
type Document = {
    template : string
    elements : Map<string, obj>
}with  
    static member Test = {
        template = "{% for item in test %} {{ item[\"name\"] }} {% endfor %}"
        elements = 
            Map.empty 
            |> Map.add "test" ([Map.empty |> Map.add "name" "Foo"] :> obj) 
    }

let genTemplate = 
    let doc = Document.Test
    let template = Template.Parse(doc.template)
    template.Render(Hash.FromDictionary(doc.elements |> Map.toSeq |> dict))
```

The expected out of this would be: `Foo` but somewhat unsurprisingly I simply get an empty string.
if I simply access `item` as opposed to `item["name"]` I get the output `["name", "Foo"]`. So is there any way to do this in dotliquid? Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: There is an open issue to fix this at https://github.com/dotliquid/dotliquid/issues/320

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A relatively easy trick is to register a filter `getName` which then lets you access the `name` property of the nested dictionary using `{{ item | getName }}`. A filter can be written as an F# method:

```
type Filters() = 
  static member getName(map:Map<string, string>) = map.["name"]

Template.RegisterFilter(typeof<Filters>)
```

If you now use the filter in your test template. Note that depending on your configured DotLiquid naming convention, you might need to use `get_name` as the name (which is also the default):

```
type Document = 
  { template : string
    elements : Map<string, obj> }
  static member Test = 
    { template = "{% for item in test %} {{ item | get_name }} {% endfor %}"
      elements = 
          Map.empty 
          |> Map.add "test" ([Map.empty |> Map.add "name" "Foo"] :> obj) }
```

With this, you get the result you were expecting:

```
let genTemplate = 
    let doc = Document.Test
    let template = Template.Parse(doc.template)
    template.Render(Hash.FromDictionary(doc.elements |> Map.toSeq |> dict))
```

Unfortunately, I'm not sure if there is a way to create parameterized filters - it might be that you'll have to write something like `getName` for each key that you want to access.